# How to prevent automatic starting function after webpage is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, audio-recording

I used this simple recorder for recording my voice:
[A plugin for recording/exporting the output of Web Audio API nodes](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)

I want to implement it to my webpage. This recording example is set to ask user for allowing microphone immediatelly when page is loaded, but I want to show this message after clicking on button record, so when user want to use this service. Also there are shown "logs", they are shown also when page is loaded. I want also to show logs after clicking on button. I think it is logical, so when user want to use recorder he is informed about this service.

Comment: document.removeEventListener("load");

Answer (score 3):

Remove executing the `init` function on window `onload` event and simply call it when needed.

Instead of

```
window.onload = function init() {...}
```

Have

```
function init() {...}
```

And

```
<button onclick="init()">Record</button>
```

Comment: I have tried it. Yes, allowing microphone was shown after click on button "record", but it didn't record any audio. Recording doesn't work. Can you offer me different way how to solve my problem??